# Google Sheets: Change currency dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

How can I change the currency on cells **C4,C5,C6,C8,C9** based on what is selected on **C3**?

C3 values: **USD,EUR,GBP,BRL**

[image: Sheet image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry, i'm ok with the formulas, but I'm very newbie on code (I'm not a developer). I've found another solution using Google Apps Script for a checkbox based conversion. I could no figured out how to customize it to my needs.

Comment: If you have not done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, as requested previously, please show what you tried...

Comment: I was able to change the cell values for a hard coded currency with the following code:

var sh = e.range.getSheet();
sh.getRange("D5:D7").setNumberFormat("$ #,##00.00");
sh.getRange("D8:D9").setNumberFormat("$ #,##00.00");

I don't know how to use the C3 value to make it dinamic.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details to it.

Comment: I think the question is clear. How can we change the currency based off of a value found in a cell. From what I'm seeing, we could use https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats and create a javascript function which toggles the number format manually. still testing it out though

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets has a very unique formula which interacts with Google Finance historical and real-time financial data. The formula is called `=GOOGLEFINANCE()`, [you can do a lot with it](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) but what you're looking for is to convert currencies:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"[from_currency][to_currency])
```

Where `[from_currency]` and `[to_currency]` are in the 3 letter [ISO 4217 currency code standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217).

As for your specific need. Since `=GOOGLEFINANCE()` need to convert from one currency to another, I've added in `Column C` some currency codes in data validation so the user can set the currency in which each item was originally quoted at (`EUR`,`USD`,`GBP`,`CAD`,`AUD`,`CNY`).

Then, in `Column F` I added the following formula:

```
=IF(C3=$C$8,D3, ROUND(D3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&C3&E3),1))
```

What it does essentially is to check `Cell C8` (which sets the currency in which you wish to see the total costs), and then calculate the current exchange rate between the quoted currency (`[from_currency]`) and the Show-in currency (`[to_currency]`) and multiply that rate by the quoted price, in `Column D`, to get the orriginal quoted price in the currency desired. The `IF` function in the formula is to skip cases where the quoted currency and the show-in currency are the same.

Here is the resulting table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help Vayehee. I'm trying to change the currency format in the cell, not convert currency values. I mean, I want to change all currency symbols in the spreadsheet without any calculations os conversions.